# spring batch step restart

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement where I have multiple steps in spring batch job and on failure of one step I should still continue to the next step. But the steps failed should be restarteable.

```
<batch:job id="myJob" restartable="true">
    <batch:step id="step1" allow-start-if-complete="false">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" start-limit="1">
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="*" to="step2"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet2" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="*" to="step3"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step3">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet3" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="*" to="step4"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step4">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet4" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="myListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

I have added exception to Tasklet3 for testing purpose.

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Tasklet4 is running");
    throw new Exception("Some error");
}
```

I have number of questions around this.

1. I am unable to achieve a status of job as FAILED if in step 3 I add 

   I want the next step to be executed but job should fail to be able to restart it.
2. Just to restart batch job I changed step3 configuration as 

   then batch job failed and step 4 is not executed.
   But 
   allow-start-if-complete="false" or start-limit="1" is not working and if I restart the job step1 still gets executed. I want step1 not to be executed on job restart.

My objective is that steps should continue to next step on failure and I should be able to restart job (job should fail) and some of the steps (step 1) above should not be executed during restarted execution.

Please help.

Comment: How are you restarting the failed job ?

Comment: Are you really sure that it was a restart of the job and not a new instance? If it is a restart, then you will find 2 entries in the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table with a reference to the same BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE entry. Please check this.

Comment: @DevG I am restarting the job using restart button the batch UI. It appears only for failed batches. I was helping someone with this problem. Now she developed some bizarre solution of storing records in db and checking. Thanks for your help.